# How can I prevent EditorTemplate logic from overriding View logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

Using MVC5 I've added view logic to disable data entry based on a value in the model. After the logic runs it is overridden by existing EditorTemplate logic - the field remains enabled. How can I make my disable logic work? This view logic runs first:

```
<div>
    @{
        object attributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" };

        if (Model.OnHold.Number == 0) {
            attributes = new { @class = "form-control datePicker" };
        }

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OnHold.DateIssued, attributes);
    }
</div>
```

Then the conflicting EditorTemplate code:

```
@model DateTime

@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, @Model.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
```

Comment: Couldn't you look at the `ViewData` object in your DateTime editor view, and override the HtmlAttributes object you normally pass with the value in the `ViewData` dictionary if it's present?

Comment: I'm not using ViewData.

Comment: I know that you currently aren't, but when you pass an object as the second param to `@Html.EditorFor()` the values are stored in the `ViewData` object of the page. In other words, you can do `ViewData["@class"]` (you may need to double check me on what the exact key in the dictionary is) within your datetime editor partial and you could use that to override your normal `new { @class = "form-control datepicker" }`

Comment: This sounds like a solution but I haven't wrapped my mind around it yet. More code would help. If you could formulate an answer it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Let me know if that answer needs more explanation or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Property, attributesObj)` and you have a custom editor view defined, you can see that the intellisense for the function says that the htmlAttributes object is also included in the `ViewData` of the view. In other words, if you access the `ViewData` property within your editor view, you should have access to the properties you're passing from your `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.OnHold.DateIssued, attributes);` statement.  Here's a simple example:

```
// Index.cshtml - assuming model.Message is of type string
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "text-danger" })

// EditorTemplates/String.cshtml
@model string
@{
    object textboxAttributes = new { @class = "text-success" };
    // Override the default @class if ViewData property contains that key
    if (ViewData.ContainsKey("class") && string.IsNotNullOrWhitespace(ViewData["class"].ToString())
    {
        textboxAttributes = new { @class = ViewData["class"] };
    }
}

@Html.TextboxFor(model => model, textboxAttributes)
```

In your case your EditorTemplate will now look like this:

```
@model DateTime

@{
    object dateAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" };

    if (ViewData.ContainsKey("disabled") && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewData["class"].ToString()))
    {
        dateAttributes = new { @class = ViewData["class"], @readonly = "readonly", @disabled = "disabled" };
    }
}

@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, @Model.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), dateAttributes)
```

Comment: That worked! I needed to remove @ from @class though. I will try to edit your answer to remove them. My if statement checks for ViewData.ContainsKey("disabled") and then re-applies the disabled attributes. Many thanks.